# How to view Coded UI in Visual Studio Premium edition

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests, regression-testing

I am unable to see Coded UI Test in Test menu of my Visual Studio 2010 Premium edition. I can see Basic Unit Test, Ordered Test, Unit Test and Unit Test Wizard only. I tried adding Coded UI Test Builder in the menu using Customize feature but it was present as disabled in menu.

Please let me know how to access Coded UI Test.

Comment: As far as I know, it's only available on Ultimate edition.

Comment: It is available in Premium edition too, my friend had a look at it and she re-installed it and since then I am able to use this feature. Thanks anyways for replying

Comment: since this problem is solved I wantto close this  thread, @HiperiX plz guide me how to do it.

Comment: @Vanshdeep How did you solve this issue. I'm now facing the same problem.